Help with understanding the solution set of a lemma
I am reading Linear Congruences in Dudley's Elementary Number Theory. I am having trouble following a part of the proof.
There is another theorem referenced in the proof I will call Theorem 4.5: If $ac \equiv bc \pmod m$ and $gcd(c,m) = d$, then $a \equiv b \pmod {m/d}$.
The lemma reads as follows:
For the linear congruence $ax\equiv b \pmod m$, let $d=gcd(a,m)$. If $d|b$, then $ax\equiv b \pmod m$ has exactly $d$ solutions.
Proof: 
If we cancel the common factor, we get a congruence $(a/d)x \equiv (b/d) \pmod {(m/d)}$, which we know has exactly one solution because $gcd(a/d, m/d)=1$. Call it $r$, and let $s$ be any other solution of $ax\equiv b \pmod m$.
Then $ar \equiv as \equiv b \pmod m$, and it follows from Theorem 4.5 that $r \equiv s \pmod {m/d}$. That is, $s-r = k(m/d)$ or $s=r + k(m/d)$ for some $k$. Putting $k=0, 1, ...,(d-1)$, we get numbers which are least residues modulus $m$, since 
$$
0\le r + k(m/d) \lt (m/d) + (d - 1)(m/d) = m,  (1) 
$$
and they all satisfy $ax\equiv b \pmod m$ because 
$$
(a/d)(r + k(m/d))\equiv (a/d)r \equiv b/d \pmod {m/d}
$$
and this implies 
$$
a(r+k(m/d))\equiv b\pmod m.
$$
End of Proof (couldn't figure out how to generate the QED symbol.).
My question is: in the equation marked (1) above, where does the expression $(m/d)+(d-1)(m/d)$ come from? I understand that usually $0\le r \lt m-1$, and in this case the author uses $s=r+k(m/d)$ for $k=0,1,...,(d-1)$ as the general solution, so I can see where $(d-1)$ comes from, but I am missing something.

Since $r$ is a solution module $m/d$, you can require $0 \leq r < m/d$. Therefore, equation (1) uses $r < m/d$ and $k \leq d-1$.

Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs. This is enforced site policy, see here.
It's best for site health to delete this answer (which also minimizes community time wasted on dupe processing.)

I still don't understand how these two inequalities, $r\lt (m/d);and;k\lt(d-1)$, lead to $r + k(m/d)\lt (m/d)+(d-1)(m/d)$?

$k \leq d-1$ implies $k(m/d) \leq (d-1)(m/d)$, then add $r < m/d$.
